# Sapply a function to create a new column in dataframe with vectorized input

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the original dataframe below:

```
> head (DATA)
  N_b N_l    A        sqr.x    e_1    e_2    e_3   e_4    e_5
1   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0
2   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0
3   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0
4   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0
5   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19
6   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19
```

I want to calculate `R` as shown in the equation below:

[image]

where `m` is dependent on `N_l` as shown below:

```
> Multi.Presence
   N_l    m
1    1 1.20
2    2 1.00
3    3 0.85
4    4 0.65
5    5 0.65
```

For each row of the data in the dataframe `DATA`, I would like to calculate `R` for all possible values of `N_l`. This means for rows 1 and 2, the code should solve for `N_1 = 1, 2, and 3` and choose the maximum value of `R`, and return which `N_l` was responsible for the maximum value of `R`.

I wrote the following code to create a function and append the new column to the original dataframe:

```
compute.R <- function(N_l, e, N_b, A, x.sqr)
{
  (c(1.2, 1, 0.85, 0.65, 0.65)[N_l] * ((N_l/N_b) + ((sum(e[1:N_l]) * A)/x.sqr)))
}

R <- sapply(seq(nrow(DATA)), function(i)
{
    with(DATA, compute.R(N_l[i], DATA[i, 5:9], N_b[i], A[i], x.sqr[i]))
})

DATA <- cbind(DATA, R=R)
```

However, this just outputs the last calculated value of `R` and not the maximum value as shown below:

```
> head (DATA)
  N_b N_l    A        sqr.x    e_1    e_2    e_3   e_4    e_5   R
1   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0    0.6573333
2   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0    0.6573333
3   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0    0.6846667
4   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0    0.6846667
5   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19   0.8666667
6   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19   0.8666667
```

I carried the calculations and this is what I should get instead:

[image]

Also, I am not sure how to have it indicate, which value of `N_l` was responsible for the maximum calculated `R`. So as the calculations in excel show: for the first four rows of `DATA`, `N_1 = 2` results in max `R` and in the last two rows `N_l = 3` results in the max `R` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R <- function(x){
  N_b <- x[1]
  N_l <- x[2]
  N_l_seq <- seq(N_l)
  A <- x[3]
  sqr.x <- x[4]
  e <- x[5:(5 + N_l - 1)]
  m <- Multi.Presence$m[N_l_seq]
  f <- m * (N_l_seq/N_b + A * cumsum(e) / sqr.x)
  c(val=max(f), pos=which.max(f))
}


cbind(df, vars = t(apply(DATA, 1, R)))

N_b N_l  A sqr.x  e_1  e_2  e_3   e_4 e_5    vars.1 vars.2
1   5   3 18   810 14.6  2.6 -9.4   0.0   0 0.7822222      2
2   5   3 18   810 14.6  2.6 -9.4   0.0   0 0.7822222      2
3   5   4 24  1440 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0 0.9266667      2
4   5   4 24  1440 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0 0.9266667      2
5   5   5 30  2250 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19 1.0880000      3
6   5   5 30  2250 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19 1.0880000      3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The column numbers in my actual dataframe are different so I updated them. But the last line where you apply the function and cbind the data, I get the error: `Error in 5 + N_l : non-numeric argument to binary operator.` I wanted to make sure if this is an error that I caused by updating the column numbers in line:   `e <- x[18:(5 + N_l - 1)]` because the `e_` columns start at column 18 of the main dataframe `DATA`. Also I still cannot tell which value of `N_l sequence` is resulting in the maximum value of `R` selected.